# What are my options if I want to compress a video before upload in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, video-encoding

I am uploading a video file which is in .mov or .mp4. I want to compress it (little loss of quality is acceptable) before uploading to Amazon S3. Is there a library in java which can accomplish that ? I found one called Xuggler but it looks a lot complex. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best **diy option** is to use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

> FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video

It's is a command line tool so can be called by a java app. [Here's a tutorial](http://rob.opendot.cl/index.php/useful-stuff/ffmpeg-x264-encoding-guide/) on how to encode to H.264

Another option is to **outsource your encoding to an encoding service** like [encoding.com](http://www.encoding.com/) or [Ankoder](http://www.ankoder.com/). Both those integrate with S3 and can upload the encoded videos to your S3 account.

Comment: @DhruvPathak - yep, I guess you could.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I found one more called JAVE http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php Its looks really good but I get a it.sauronsoftware.jave.InputFormatException for libx264 codec :(

Comment: @Prabhat - That is just a wrapper around ffmpeg anyway. From your link: JAVE is not pure Java: it acts as a wrapper around an ffmpeg (http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/) executable.

Comment: @Geoff - Yes. I know that. But it simplifies coding.  Can you please provide a link where Java wrapper for FFmpeg or Mencoder is provided ?

Comment: @Prabhat -Sorry, I don't understand what you want? You already have a Java wrapper for ffmpeg.

Comment: @Geoff - Yes. I have a wrapper but like I said I get a it.sauronsoftware.jave.InputFormatException for libx264 codec.

Comment: @Prabhat - I don't know of any other java wrappers but I'm sure there probably are some out there. Some distributions of ffmpag don't include libx264 to avoid patent lawsuits, so you might want to check whether its even included with jave.